# How to comunicate with another app over a network?

Tags: python, c#, reactjs, network-programming, backend

Newbie here. I'm writing a connect-four game with reactjs for learning purposes. I want to make it multiplayer having both players on different networks but I don't know where to start with the backend. I was thinking of writing a simple server (maybe an http server that just receives post request?) using python or c# that has a table of pairs with players that are matched up together. I think the table would need the IP and port of both players (maybe just the IP). It would be something like the following:

Player A makes a move -> A-frontend sends data to backend -> backend receives data and fowards it to Player B -> B-frontend updates screen to show A's move.

If anyone has comments, advice or knows about a good source to learn, that would be awesome..

Answer (score 0):

Connect-4 is not an FPS game which requires real-time update. I think your logic is good.

Since there is a clear order of action, you can have a function like `wait_for_action(player_index:int)` and another function like `update_board()`.

You can use flask to test it locally. The official document is good.

```
for i in range(max_number_of_actions_possible):
    player_to_act = i%2
    res = wait_for_action(player_to_act) # store the result
    update_board(res) # update the board and send to every member
    # check game breaking conditions, etc
```